# Microservices architecture on cloud advice needed

Tags: rest, graphql, microservices

I am building a system based on microservices. It is a web application connected to different rest APIS. Now I want to implement the authorization system, (not authentication), so basically I want to be able to define, which users on the system can perform which actions.
So I am thinking to implement a role/permission system for that.

However, I have a dilemma about the two different architecture options that come to my mind, I and would like to know your thoughts, advices, pros and cons, to move forward with it.

There will be a specific microservice to handle the user permissions and roles, so basically this microservice will have access to two database tables making the association between the user and roles, and roles and permissions. This is the common part to the two solutions I have considered.

Now both options with pros and cons in my opinion:

1) Keeping for each microservice, a cache table with the user permissions specific to that microservice. So, every time a user wants to perform an action on that microservice (let's say, delete an order on the ordering microservice), the microservice will check that table, granting or not access to the user to perform the action.

Pros: every microservice is really a microservice, an independent service that can work totally autonomously of the rest of the system. If the main microservice handling the user permission crashes and it is not available, the rest of microservices will continue to work.

Cons: If I update the user permissions in the microservice that handles this, I need to send a message to all microservices to update their correspondent permissions tables.

2) Creating a API gateway microservice to act as a middleware between the frontend and the rest of microservices and use graphql in it. Frontend will no longer know about the rest of microservices, only will know about this one.
This microservice will intercept all request from the frontend, check with the user-permissions microservice if the user has permission to do the action, and if so, calling the correspondent microservice.

Pros: All the business logic to decide if the user has or not access is in a single microservice, instead of being duplicated across microservices. Also, authentication only needs to be implemented in the middleware microservice, no need to double check if the user is authenticated on the internal microservices as if we got there, is because we were succesfully authenticated previously.
No need to update cache tables in the internal microservices if the user roles  or permissions are updated.

Cons: This defeats the definition of microservice architecture. I.e If the middleware microservice crashes, the whole system will be down.

I would like to know your thoughts!!

Thank you!

Comment: You make a false assumption about the gateway having to be a bottleneck. Note that gateway doesn't need to be a single node - usually it's implemented as a cluster (with a load-balancing strategy). If properly designed (statelessness) it should be fairly easy to scale.

Comment: i agree with jannis api gateway is always a cluster. i would go with api gateway this is preferred approach in modern architecture and single place of entry. it's relatively easy and provides you better debugging and control.  another way to use distributed cache like redis and all microservices look into cache first. if you update permissions simply invalidate cache and first request reloads value